# Spring bean id conflict

Tags: spring, javabeans, autowired

I'm a new Spring user, and probably doing something wrong (due to a misunderstanding of the concepts/internals of Spring IOC), so hopefully this question will result in a simple answer.

Here's what I'm trying to do: I'm trying to use two beans from two different 3rd party libraries:

```
<bean id="validator" class="org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI" factory-method="validator"/>
<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>
```

The problem is that they both have the same Id, and that is not allowed.  I'm trying to auto-wire the ESAPI validator, and the LocalValidatorFactoryBean is used by spring if I followed correctly.

So my simplified class for using the ESAPI validator would be:

```
public class ValidatedString {
    @Autowired(required=true)
    Validator stringValidator; 

    public void doSomethingWithTheValidator() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

But what I can't understand is how I can change the Id.  Both return a Validator class, from a different package, and I was under the impression that the id field needs to be the same as the class name.

Help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried changing the `id`'s? Both the `id` and `name` attributes are up to yourself, there is no requirement that they be the same as the class name, it's just a bit easier to figure out what the beans "are" that way.

When beans are `@Autowired`, Spring will use the best match based on either name, type (default as I recall) or constructor and so if your `Validator` in the `ValidatedString` class is an `org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI` then that's what will be injected.

Cheers,

Comment: Still working on fixing the real problem (that's an item for another question), but I guess the id's were just a small issue I had to get out of the way to make progress.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
<bean id="esapiValidator" class="org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI" factory-method="validator"/>
<bean id="localValidator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>
```

Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
<bean id="validator" class="org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI" factory-method="validatorFactory"/>
<bean id="validatorFactory" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>
```

ids and references such as `factory-method` are usually up to you.